# The function ignore_user_abort() - what is a script's tty?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand what is meant by a script tty:

> When running PHP as a command line script, and **the script's tty goes
>   away** without the script being terminated then the script will die
>   the next time it tries to write anything, unless value is set to TRUE

Comment: Any reasons for the downvotes and close vote? :(

Comment: What? A little background information on where you got this would help. I stared, thinking about it for a good 10 minutes before I realized this wasn't you just saying something random but you quoting the manual. A quick google for "TTY" will show you what it means. The fourth google result for me brought back this page: http://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for which covers it.

Comment: 1. Don't be rude. 2. I did google for it. 3. Text in yellow on stack overflow means it's a quote.

Comment: 1. Honestly, I know it comes across as rude, but I'm not trying to be. 2. I can type your question into google and get several results that can answer the question, all on the first page. Maybe I'm just missing something. 3. I know that yellow is a quote. But what are you quoting? Yourself, one of the many random pages on the internet? A little context can go a long way, even for something like a definition, just saying "Hey, I was reading [this] page in the manual and don't understand what they mean by XXX" would have helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every shell program runs with stdin,stdout,stderr and the stdout & stderr default to /dev/ttyX ... the console for the logged in user

if you launch php like
      php myprogram.php 1>output.txt 2>error.txt
then the results will be retained
to combine both out+err into one file use
      php myprogram.php >results.txt 2>&1